# statistical test for relationship between variables that are measured at different times

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, anova

I measured the number of symptoms in an animal model during two time spans:

time 1- lasted 30d

after 30d I measured symptoms again

time 2- lasted 8d

I noticed that symptoms took over two weeks two develop in time 1 but occured right away during time 2.

The time of day I measured symptoms differed between time spans 1 and 2.
I check symptoms once a day but at relatively different times between days(non-randomized).

**I would like to know if symptoms were more likely associated with a specific time of day**

At first I considered combining time span 1 and 2 but then I decided to separate them and analyze them this way. At this point, I am unsure of what statistical test to run but was considering ANOVA factor analysis.